# Make a little space after a longtable and before a caption

Tags: longtable

I'm trying to make a table which is not centered in the page, so I've used this structure to define it. But, I need to make a little vertical space between the bottom of that table and its caption. How do I to deal that please ? I can't find a solution.

```
\lipsum[2]
\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{4cm}|p{7cm}|}
\hline
COL1 & COL2 & COL3 \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3
\hline
\caption[]{Hi title.}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\lipsum[2]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an empty row:

```
\multicolumn{3}{l}{} \\[-7pt]
```

and adjust `[-7pt]` as per needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[2]
\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{4cm}|p{7cm}|}
\hline
COL1 & COL2 & COL3 \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
 \multicolumn{3}{l}{} \\[-7pt]           %% added new
\caption[]{Hi title.}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Option -2:

With `caption` package and its `skip`:

```
\captionsetup{skip=10pt}
```

inside the group so that the effect  is local.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[2]
\begingroup
\captionsetup{skip=10pt}        %% this line added
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{4cm}|p{7cm}|}
\hline
COL1 & COL2 & COL3 \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\caption[]{Hi title.}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]